# Snap 3D Cursor to Grease Pencil Surface (Blender 2.8)

Tags: grease-pencil, 3d-cursor

Is there a way to snap the 3D Cursor to a grease pencil drawing?

With User Preferences > Interface > Cursor Depth checked, the 3D cursor will snap to the surface beneath it.

This works with everything but grease pencil strokes.  I've tried vertex snapping as well, it seems the points of a grease pencil stroke aren't considered vertices.

I've drawn a tree trunk that curves in 3D space and would like to draw branches coming out of it.  I can manually place the 3D cursor but aligning it with the trunk is a pain as the cursor won't snap to the existing grease pencil strokes.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting the "Stroke" option in the Stroke Placement dropdown will let your strokes stick to other strokes.

I needed to download the latest beta build for this option to be there, but it works like a charm :)

[image: Stroke Option]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of Blender and assuming you have your `GPencil object` selected inside `Draw Mode`...

1. Go to `Edit Mode`
2. Activate the `Select Lasso` tool in the Toolbar (left sidebar)
3. Select the point(s) where the 3D will be placed
4. `Grease Pencil` menu (headbar) → `Snap` → `Cursor to Selected`

— Done! The 3D Cursor has been positioned

5. Go back to `Draw Mode`